# How to pre-train a deep neural network (or RNN) with unlabeled data?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Recently, I was asked about how to pre-train a deep neural network with unlabeled data, meaning, instead of initializing the model weight with small random numbers, we set initial weight from a pretrained model (**with unlabeled data**).

Well, intuitively, I kinda get it, it probably helps with the vanishing gradient issue and shorten the training time when there are not too much labeled data available. But still, I don't really know how it is done, how can you train a neural network with unlabeled data? Is it something like SOM or Boltzmann machine?

Has anybody heard about this? If yes, can you provide some links to sources or papers. I am curious. Greatly appreciate!

Comment: I've answered, but this question may be more appropriate on a site like cross-validated. Would not be surprised to see it migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to deep-learn from unlabeled data. Layerwise pre-training was developed back in the 2000s by Geoff Hinton's group, though that's generally fallen out of favor.

More modern unsupervised deep learning methods include Auto-Encoders, Variational Auto-Encoders, and Generative Adversarial Networks. I won't dive into the details of all of them, but the simplest of these, auto-encoders, work by compressing an unlabeled input into a low dimensional real-valued representation, and using this compressed representation to reconstruct the original input. Intuitively, a compressed *code* that can effectively be used to recreate an input is likely to capture some useful features of said input. See [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/Autoencoders/) for an illustration and more detailed description. There are also plenty of examples implemented in your deep learning library of choice.

I guess in some sense any of the listed methods could be used as pre-training, e.g for preparing a network for a discriminative task like classification, though I'm not aware of that being a particularly common practice. Initialization methods, activation functions, and other optimization tricks are generally advanced enough to do well without more complicated initialization procedures.

Comment: Thanks, It sounds weird but make sense, so, it means using the auto-encoders to train each layer separately and then take the weights as initial weight of the original neural network

Comment: If you were to use an auto-encoder as a pre-training technique, I don't think you would use it to train each layer separately. Rather you would train an auto-encoder, then grab the encoder portion of the network and re-use those layers in another architecture. In that case, those encoder layers have been trained jointly, not separately. Again, I'm not sure I've ever seen a paper take that approach, but it wouldn't surprise me.